# TS complains that argument of type "never" is not provided

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I want to make a function more flexible, by allowing as parameters either:

- an element of type number
- any generic element  + a converter function that converts it into a number

```
type ElementConvertor<T> = T extends number ? never : (element: T) => number

function isNumber(x: any): x is number {
    return typeof x === "number"
}

function evaluate<T>(element: T, toNumber: ElementConvertor<T>) {
    if (isNumber(element)) return element
    else return toNumber(element)
}


const main = () => {
    const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
    const array1Value = array1.map(x => evaluate(x)); 
    // -> TS compiler complains here 
    //input.tsx(7, 34): An argument for 'toNumber' was not provided.


    const array2 = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }]
    const array2Value = array2.map((x => evaluate(x, ({ value }) => value)))


    console.log(array1Value, array2Value)
}
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAwgexQNwgJ2E3wB4AVAPigF4oyoIAPYVAEwGcoUBXRAIwJQA-Fwh58UAFxQAFBATI00sgEoaVHvwIAobQDNuKAMbAAltiin2AOV4D8MxtICGKECumNLnTfagBvbShgqHwIYG58FChQSEw9KC9qZKgAIl8CVO0AX10DYzMLMWc4bmcWcgo5BVRgZQAaGMxbLXxpeCRarFwCIlJKNUCQywSZKxb7as60FTUwiKiGGrQgkPl2aHnI6KIJginFYBUc3W0jbHZgKERnU2jaGTVqKiGQ85RLqGd8fGcQAEYaFAANr-RoAJkaAGYALoAblWwXen2+vwBADUStxoLRUX9-gA6G5gRzqBg4LHlCCOWYIxFQZFXPEgcFA4H+KAU0oQaSA7KNDlc7HSVn8gKcrE8qBQqDZGH0xlfH5-cGY7lA5ngonOEmk57kyksRyNGSCyWyp5UIUQWbHXTDZGYBAEuCYADmMmZ-zV2Mamp9NpOQA)

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use typescript overload signatures. [docs on Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Overloading signatures and implementation:

```js
//delcare overload signatures
function evaluate(element: number): number;
function evaluate<T>(element: T, toNumber: ElementConvertor<T>): number;

// implementation has to be compatibel with all overload signatures
function evaluate<T>(element: T, toNumber?: ElementConvertor<T>) {
    if (isNumber(element)) return element
    else {
        if (toNumber !== undefined) {
            return toNumber(element)
        } else {
            //even though it is not easy possible we have to handle it
            throw new Error(`Cannot evaluate, the toNumber is not defiend, input is not a number. Input value: ${element}`)
        }
    }
}
```

Have in mind types are not guaranteed so that you can easy fail with the following code regardless of the approach:

```js
evaluate({} as number);
evaluate(undefined as any as number);
```

[Typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAwgexQNwgJ2E3wB4AVAPigF4oyoIAPYVAEwGcoUBXRAIwJQA-Fwh58UAFxQAFBATI00sgEoaVHvwIAobQDNuKAMbAAltiin2AOV4D8MxtICGKECumNLnTfagBvbShgqHwIYG58FChQSEw9KC9qZKgAIl8CVO0AX10AejzWeSNnMKhMcThMZ1YodlMAcxRnCLD2fUMTc2ixZzhuFog5BVRgaQz8Dy47AgBuDuMzC17%20wfIKYaRR5QAaGMxbLXxpeC20LFwCIlJKKYn57QLLRDARtBbuqAALZ04iKAEUCMmBeHwEcCgAHdTMAvlA%20hCKgQqjU6o1mq0IO0DItPisBix1ptFGM6HsiId7EITm8MNhxNd1mpAiFLAkZFZKQRiaMVGowq0erSgiF5OxoCzWSFTOyKTMJABCFKGIp6UwoCCsZkiqVSgWRaJyo48tAqHVS7IMODigLm3XBApiVAxL6YbjASweqxcTAeiC-EBQMCYdj1PgIKHQH54fbfVysCMwu322H4TCQ0QZmD4NMOAAG6FcKF9DBwfQJEHJX2gRr83uLHtVpjYe3VYHd3h9Huc0yOADooABJFDtj1l-oQaQAEn88jOwGyebN9qguVZuVyumBKHYHsQznVNFkamoVElwW3u-hOecIAAjEeANp3vYAJj2AGYALrzVmX7s3veABq5bQLQpT4Led59vuYCOOopbloMjh8g8f7YFeEG3q%20T7%20FA47cJOUAPtkex4QRRE4aRAT4aB0gfquX7mv%2016QSAr4gROR5YexMHOHB8GnohqwsI4ewyORoGrieVAUXyZrmgU1ZlN6roZpC0AlNEegHnA5rAPggbnlK%20LIf4lq-L29gqL%20ISWiUwBGHCcjaiuMqyAwlg7sArhGBA8SwDmxCuSuISXpgCB9gQuYyKkACaWJ7BpUA6aYCCsH2qRQAA1AwMFYuwzgNBAy72paYoSsmurhZF0XELFCXsEl0Cpelex8B2DZQjCcJMJAJiaoFuapKVuprnZujoTuEUQH2VQNDIPF3pxhF7DxHGgWauRAA)

Comment: Sure these would work but doesn't it seem overkill here? 
I'm surprised my current typing is rejected by the compiler and I'd rather understanding what I am doing wrong

Comment: You are trying to use the type `never` to be considered as `optional`. I am not sure this is achievable with typescript. Let's see  someone can prove me wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're able to inline the behaviour you want with a conditional type like this:

```
function evaluate<T>(element: T, ...[toNumber]: T extends number ? [] : [toNumber: (element: T) => number]) {
    if (typeof toNumber !== "undefined") return toNumber(element);

    return element;
}
```

However, this isn't as readable as using overloads, but it does work.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgQk6m)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree the overload solution seems clearer